# React: dynamic position doesn't work on first render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a container Component that is draggable with the mouse and will drag all the children with it.  I have it mostly working but not the initial placement. I pass into the component and x,y and that sets the state variables.  In the render I am passing those variable as the style to the div. The initial placement is per the css (or 0 if not set in css).  then when I first drag it jumps to the passed in coordinates.  I have a log statement in the render and every render gets the right state variables

I tried a dummy update of the state in componentDidMount to see if I could trick it to behave like it does when dragging but no change.

```
.draggable {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #cca;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

export default class Draggable extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
        super(); 
         this.state = {
               preDragPos: {x:props.initialX, y:props.initialY},
               pos: {x:props.initialX, y:props.initialY},
               dragging: false,
               rel: null // Initial Mouse Down location
           }

....
Use mouse up/down/move to modify this.state.pos
....
 render () {
      const dragStyle = {
        left: this.state.pos.x,
        top: this.state.pos.y,
      };
      console.log("Render", dragStyle);

      return (
      <div className="draggable" style={dragStyle} onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>      
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's weird, your code works perfectly fine on my computer. Have you tried inspecting the first render of your div to make sure its attributes are corrects? Maybe there is a css side effect from another part of your app

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the x and y correctly to your component? It should be something like this:  <Draggable initialX={100} initialY={100} />

Comment: Thanks HermitCrab that was exactly it I had "100" not {100} and of course it printed fine in the log statement.  Transitioning from C++ yo javascript and the lack of type casting is killing me.

Comment: Great. I know what you mean, I'm also transitioning from C++. Could you edit your post and mark it as fixed

Comment: As i finally made a stack over flow account as appose to just lurking I don't have enough reputation yet. There is no checkmark next to your answer for me to click. This seems a very odd choice by stack overflow.

Comment: I didn't write an answer, but just a comment, therefore you cannot accept it :) But you can update your post and explain how you fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user hermitcrab.  When I created the component I passed in the parameters as  "100" not {100}. The console.log for both appear identical but their effects is not.